# Why Can't I add a project reference to unit test project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I am getting this strange error where I simply want to use some classes from another project that exists within the same solution.
To make this more clear I will paste some images in the question.

**My solution explorer:**

[image: Solution explorer]

As you can see the DependencyCheckAPI project is added to the project references, but I still can't use it in my classes.

In the image below you will see that the DependencyCheckAPI is not recognized, and the same goes for the AzureStorage Class. When I use the helper (when you hover your mouse over the problem), adding the reference to "DependencyCheckAPI" is suggested. When I click it, noting happens.

**What I have tried:**

So I have tried to add it via the suggestion popup menu (which does nothing), and add it manually by selecting add reference and then adding it via the menu (displays it in the references list from the unit test project, but cant be referenced in the unit test).
I have checked the names, namespaces and if there is a circular dependency (there is not).

[image]

Since the popup helper does not help I don't really know where to go from here. Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Update:

The comments suggested that I have the wrong .NET version in my unit test project. The problem is these are the only options I have for creating a new one:

[image]

Comment: Did you check the used framework? The framework version of the test-project has to be greater or equal to the framework version of DependencyCheckApi-project

Comment: The class you want to use is actually public in that assembly?

Comment: @Ralf Yes they are public, I am going to check the versions now

Comment: @Heslacher From my main project the Target Framework is .NET 6.0 and from the unit tests project is it .NET Framework 4.7.2 (I used the suggested from visual studio with both)

Comment: Well that is just the problem. Switch the test-project to .NET 6.0 and you can add the reference

Comment: Create .NET 6 project fir unit tests.

Comment: @Heslacher in my visual studio the Unit Test Project (.NET Framework) only goes up to .NET Framework 4.8

Comment: The most flexible thing to do is to target your `DependencyCheckApi` assembly to `.NET Standard 2.0`. If you can do that, then anything targeted at .Net 4..6.1 or any later version (including .NET Core 2.0 and .NET 7) will be able to use it. (You won't be able to do this if you're using almost any UI classes though. )

Comment: Is "downgrading" your main-project to 4.8 a possibility?

Comment: The "(.NET Framework)" in the template name means it is for the "old" Framework (pre-Core). The various "Test Projects" without it are for the newer ("Core") versions (5 and up)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so @Heslachter gave me the solution. It was indeed using the wrong .NET version, but not only that. My main project is a .NET Core 6.0 project and the Unit test was a .NET Framework test.

Obviously those are not going to work together, so when I created a new test project for .NET core, it worked.

Thanks for the responses!